# why this self-closing TITLE tag breaks my web page

Tags: css, html

I have a very simple webpage.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

breaks my webpage ,both in Chrome and Firefox

the issue is with self-closing Title tag ,removing TITLE tag or adding a title fix the issue

```
<title>Test Page</title>
```

Whats the issues with self-closing TITLE tags , couldn't find any reference to say its invalid

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a void element:

```
<img />
<br />
```

Then they have no ***content***, because there's nowhere to put it. Images can be thought of as an empty `<div>` with a background image.

Compared to these elements:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<section>World</section>
```

Which actually contain stuff (in this case, text).

The reason that the `<title/>` breaks your page is because you ***need*** a title in a webpage - if you don't have one, it'll just display the URL of the page, for example:

```
google.com/index.html
```

You need to have a valid title, and `<title>` is not a void element. This is why it breaks. To see this, go to a HTML validation website (e.g. https://validator.w3.org) and see what it tells you.

In short - `<title>` is not a void element - it requires an opening and closing tag.

EDIT: Research showed me [this website](https://htmlreference.io/element/title/), which says:

```
Self-closing: No
```

So in short they're not self-closing elements. You can find a list of self-closing elements [here](http://xahlee.info/js/html5_non-closing_tag.html).

Comment: I did the validation with my correct html , not the one above which didn't complain about the self-closing title, but when i use this it shows error

Comment: No no, i meant the html i've added in the Question.

Comment: Oh, well it is invalid HTML, that's probably why

Comment: Yes, im using a tool to convert unformatted html to formatted , that tool does this conversion,

Comment: That tool is what probably broke your title