# HtmlAgilityPack unable to parse html with <title/>

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have the following html string (simplified version of the HTML which is not controlled by me):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      Hello How are you doing?
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

and I am using the following code to parse it using HtmlAgilityPack:

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(htmlStr);
```

but this is the value of `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.InnerHtml`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title></head></html>
```

As you can see the html was not parsed correctly.

On some trial and error I noticed that on replacing `<title/>` in the html string with `<title></title>`, the doc was parsed correctly. How can I parse such HTML doc with HAP correctly?

Fiddle link: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CZv09l

### Edit

The source html string is not in my control, though before parsing with HAP I can replace all self closed `<title/>` but I am not sure if it would be feasible to do so for all other self-closed tags, as I found HAP doesn't work well with `<p/>` as well. Or is there a fast way to replace all self-closed tags with their expanded version? (I am considering the additional cost here, as I may have to do it for ~70 large html files while the user waits for them to complete)

Fiddle link for issue with `<p/>` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/VGJ1G6

Comment: Title tags shouldn't be self closing, so this is invalid HTML. If you have control over this, either populate the tag or omit it entirely.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why this self-closing TITLE tag breaks my web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53147142/why-this-self-closing-title-tag-breaks-my-web-page)

Comment: @JonathonChase the OP states that the input is not under their control. Since HtmlAgilityPack states they are tolerant to malformed documents, this looks like a bug.

Comment: I have edited the question to add more details. Thanks for all your help so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can find default settings for parsing html tags [here](https://github.com/zzzprojects/html-agility-pack/blob/5f82294ea08802aac90d53074f6eef6f934634eb/src/HtmlAgilityPack.Shared/HtmlNode.cs#L94) in source code. Changing setting for `<title>` tag helps to parse your html:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags["title"] = HtmlElementFlag.Closed;

var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
```

[Fiddler code.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2rkGDQ)
Similarly you can easily change default behaviour for all needed tags.
Also there is already defined setting for `<p>` tags:

```
HtmlDocument.DisableBehaviorTagP = false; //false for automatically closing
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I am trying to understand how will these changes impact the parsing of other html docs? And if you can also help with how do these enums impact the parsing, HtmlElementFlag.Empty, HtmlElementFlag.CData, HtmlElementFlag.Closed. By reading the comments I got some sense, but still asking in case you can provide some more details.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know further details except those that I've got from the comments and cannot help you to asses the impact.